# Internal Server Error uploading image in Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure

I created a basic drag and drop image upload user interface in a .Net MVC application. I just save the image to the server using very basic code, this works locally , but after I deploy to Azure I get a javascript alert that pops up saying "Internal Server Error" which is weird because no where in my code do I have  anything to show an alert with the status.

here is the code I tried:

(basically taken from Phil Haack article)

```
public ActionResult UploadPhoto(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var splitFileName = file.FileName.Split('.');
            var type = splitFileName[splitFileName.Length - 1];
            var fileName = User.Identity.Name;
            var path = "/Content/Users/" + fileName + "." + type;               
            var pathToSave = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Users"), fileName + "." + type);
            file.SaveAs(pathToSave);
        }

        return Json("All files have been successfully stored.");
    }
```

something is preventing this upload from happening on Azure , anyone have any ideas?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, you're hitting an uncaught exception. One thing you could do is catch the exception and return the stacktrace back to the client to see what's causing the error.

Comment: that is true , but the exception has to be due to uploading the image , an upload that worked fine locally , and was taken off phil haack's blog  - so has absolutely been tested.  So... I was hoping someone  knows off the top of their head what config setting needs to be changed to be able to upload images to a website server hosted on Azure

Comment: I would be guessing but I think it has something to do with file save. Could be that you don't have access to the path when the code is run in Azure. BTW, are you deploying your code in an Azure Website or Azure Cloud Service?

Comment: What do your logs say about the 500 error? I wouldn't be surprised if there's an ACCESS_DENIED in there somewhere. Is the upload location for the files ACL'd appropriately?

Comment: It is Azure Website ,  I haven't gone through and got the actual error , but I am sure it is something along the lines of access denied .   It is just in a folder called "Content/UserImages"  off the root in the web app

Comment: I suspect you'll find access denied (or doesn't exist) for the file uploads path you are providing. If you intend to store files you should really update the code to push the file to Azure Blob storage because local filesystem access not the right way to do this for Websites or Web Roles where you site may be moved or reprovisioned without your controle.

Comment: I think you have no write permission. To be sure, add a try catch around your file.SaveAs() and return the exception message. Only for test.  :)

Comment: "I haven't gone through and got the actual error" << This is problem number 1. It isn't possible for anyone to do anything better than guess without an actual error. Always, always, always get the error first. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot upload images to azure web servers like that. Your website does not have permissions to make changes to file systems outside of publishing. You will have to use Blob or CDN services provided by Azure or another service to host user uploaded content.

Comment: it was actually a lot easier then I thought . it's what I figured - just hoping that someone knew of a hack , but this is obivously better to start out the right way